# Question of duplicity of a question

Tags: discussion, duplicates

It is possible or okay to flag a question as a duplicate if it was asked earlier, and the one asked later already has an accepted answer but the context is very similar:

Consider this question:

[How do I connect Internet from a laptop using USB modem to a Galaxy S3, or directly USB modem(data card) to S3 for internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32680/galaxy-s3-usb-modem-connection) (2012)

and

[Share Wifi over USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159686/share-wifi-over-usb) (2016) (with accepted answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Especially with the examples quoted, all the more so. Older question is not clear and OP didn't revise to make it clear. Only answer to that is based on a *supposition* of OP's intent. Newer question is clear in intent and has a detailed answer (with a bounty awarded )

Marking the older question duplicate of the newer one would benefit those who land up at older question.

Timeline doesn't matter - what matters is that a clear question with upvoted / accepted answer remains with other question being marked duplicate. If both of them have good answers and questions are similar in content, it should be flagged for *merging*
( This is my understanding from moderators in chats)

Comment: Spot on.  We want the best question/answer to become the primary.

Comment: And while mergers are rare, they happen from time to time. I vaguely remember @MatthewRead did one a couple of years ago #D